# Separation of Concerns?

Tags: apex, design-patterns, architecture

I would learn more about SoC in Salesforce but I have a question.

Are these concepts really used during the projects or are only "theoretical and academic concepts" never used in real life for problems regarding time, difficulty to implement etc?

I love topics regarding Software Engineering, Design Pattern etc but I have never seen SoC in a real Salesforce project. Maybe because I am still young ;)

Comment: They are very real, and some manner of separation of concerns is very important as an organization's scale (both in terms of code base and data volume) grows larger.

Comment: This reads a bit too much like a discussion question, try to focus on a specific, objective question, with a real world answer. Ie, "How can I use SOC to separate my lightning apps?", or as Adrian phrased it, "How can I use SOC to increase my test coverage?".

Comment: you should come and work at my org - SoC is what we do, every day. :-)

Comment: There is a [Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_patterns_sl/units/apex_patterns_sl_soc) on this topic.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it should be considered with every single method you write. Each line of code—or if you want to go deeper than that, each cyclomatic branching within your code—is vulnerable to trying to do more than it should. Separation Of Concerns will help you focus on having your code Do One Thing.

I actually spent several [slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1e_6-KS0a0CfifqYrf1iu9E-C3fTr0AZP_5Vej5eHEAE/edit#slide=id.g34ce35aca7_0_138) talking about these concepts during my talk on Simple Trigger Handlers at Snowforce2018, and intend to write it up in a blog post or few this weekend if I can get over the cold I picked up while flying back home.

Andrew Fawcett describes it as an "enterprise design pattern" [in the technical library](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Separation_of_Concerns) and goes into more depth on what it is and why you might use it. I think it's a principle more than a pattern, but the benefits are clear when applied correctly:

- Lower application complexity
- Simplify your test suite
- Make your code base easier to read/reuse/extend

---

As a simple example of when SOC is useful, consider the [Selector](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector) library and its use case. A typical implementation might mix filter and action, two concerns which should probably be separated.

```
/*
* @param newRecords - Corresponds to trigger.new
* @param oldMap - Corresponds to trigger.oldMap
*/
public static void doStuff(List<Opportunity> newRecords, Map<Id, Opportunity> oldMap)
{
    for (Opportunity record : trigger.new)
    {
        if (trigger.oldMap == null || record.OwnerId != trigger.oldMap.get(record.Id).OwnerId)
        {
            // action implementation
        }
    }
}
```

Really you're doing two separate things here, and it would be better (in my opinion) to write them as separate concerns:

```
public static Select.Filter hasOwnerChanged()
{
    return Select.Field.HasChanged(Opportunity.OwnerId);
}

/*
* @param records - A filter list of Opportunity records whose OwnerId has changed
*/
public static void doStuff(List<Opportunity> records)
{
    for (Opportunity record : records)
    {
        // action implementation
    }
}
```

What benefit do you gain from application of SOC here? It will be much easier to test your application. You can now test your filtering logic quite rigorously, and not need to worry about setting up your data to pass those filters when trying to test the action more rigorously. The same type of benefit can be achieved across a wide variety of methods, classes, etc. If you keep your methods focused and highly cohesive, writing a suite of rigorous, atomic unit tests is going to be much more natural and easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

It may also be worth taking up some further reading on this one - Andrew Fawcett's "Force.com Enterprise Architecture" or the more recent "Apex Design Patterns" by Jitendra Zaa and Anshul Verma.

They both cover the broader subject of applying best software development practises and patterns in the Salesforce context.